# Loop through child elements and and a numbered class to each li

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through the child elements of a `ul` and add a numbered class to each. Most of the code works, but I get a undefined error for the `.offset()`. Can anyone please help me resolve why?

This is a PHP based website, the code generates the class `.services` and a panel with the same class as an ID

```
var countServices = $("#services-menu ul li");
// console.log(countServices.length);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < countServices.length; i++) {
  // console.log("services" + i)

  $(".services" + i).click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked on .services" + i)
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#services" + i).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
};
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code and create maybe a snippet of the problem

Comment: `$("#services"+i)` or `$(".services"+i)` ?????

Comment: This is a php based website, the code generates the class .services and a panel with the same class as an ID

Comment: Don't use incremental ids or classes. Group elements properly. You can achieve what you need here with a single event handler placed on all the `.services` elements that selects the related element to scroll to by its index.

Comment: Rory that wont work for the way this code is dynamically created, I need tp target them in the way specified

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overcomplicated the thing, and  i is in wrong place. That will be always 1 more.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vcjdx42x/2/

Try this:

```
<div id="services0">lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="services1">lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="services2">lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="services3">lorem ipsum</div>

<div id="services-menu">
    <ul >
        <li class="services0">0</li>
        <li class="services1">1</li>
        <li class="services2">2</li>
        <li class="services3">3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    i = 0;
    $("#services-menu ul li").each(function (idx, obj) {
        var name = "#services" + i;
        console.log(name);
        $(this).click(function() {
            console.log($(this));
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(name).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
        i++;
    });


</script>
```

Comment: These creates a weird glitch where it doesnt scroll down, but when I move the mouse it flicks around, assume some kind of conflict?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Check the updated js. If you can show me your actual code I could help.

Comment: Yes its a problem with my code not yours :) The code is on here: http://aspire.design-image.co.uk/, its specific to the services section menu which shows on mobile view. I think the conflict is the script I use for filtering

Comment: What do you mean "glitch"? I see no problem with the code. You mean that empty space between the box and the top of the page or what?

Comment: Well when I click on something on the services drop down, it does not scroll down. Then when i goto scroll down manually, the screen freezes for a second and try to do the animation